# $f(x,y,r,s)=0,g(x,y,r,s)=0, then \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}= -\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}\frac{ds}{dx}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The full question is Q6.86 in the picture.[image: Question 6.86]

How do you prove, $f(x,y,r,s)=0,g(x,y,r,s)=0, then \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial y}{\partial s}\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}=0?$.

I got,
$$df=f_xdx=f_ydy+f_rdr+f_sds=0$$
$$dg=g_xdx=g_ydy+g_rdr+g_sds=0$$

Letting x and y be a function of r and s,

$$dx=x_rdr+x_Sds, dy=y_rdr+y_Sds$$

After subbing in dx and dy into the above equations, I do not have any idea how to continue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are $f$ and $g$? Are they arbitrary functions? What if $f$ and $g$ are constantly $0$, for example? Nothing could be concluded about $y$, $r$, or $s$, especially about their relationships to $x$ or their derivatives.

Comment: I think the problem has something to do with the Implicit Function Theorem, which lets one express x and y as a function of r and s, and by working out the Jacobian one could find the partials of x and y with respect to r and s. Correct me if I'm wrong because I'm quite new to the theorem as well.

Answer (score 1):

After some thinking I finally came up with a solution to the question. I've decided to post it here in case anyone else wants the answer.

$$F(x,y,r,s)=0, G(x,y,r,s)=0$$
$$dF=F_xdx+F_ydy+F_rdr+F_Sds=0$$
$$dG=G_xdx+G_ydy+G_rdr+G_Sds=0$$

Working out dy/dr, x and y are functions of r and s
$$F_x\frac{dx}{dr}+F_y\frac{dy}{dr}+F_r\frac{dr}{dr}+F_S\frac{ds}{dr}=0$$
$$G_x\frac{dx}{dr}+G_y\frac{dy}{dr}+G_r\frac{dr}{dr}+G_S\frac{ds}{dr}=0$$

As s and r are independent and dr/dr=1,

$$F_x\frac{dx}{dr}+F_y\frac{dy}{dr}+F_r=0$$
$$G_x\frac{dx}{dr}+G_y\frac{dy}{dr}+G_r=0$$
$$F_x\frac{dx}{dr}+F_y\frac{dy}{dr}=-F_r$$
$$G_x\frac{dx}{dr}+G_y\frac{dy}{dr}=-G_r$$

$$ \frac{dy}{dr}=\frac{
    \begin{vmatrix}
    F_x&  -F_r\\
    G_x & -G_r  \\
    \end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
    F_x&  F_y\\
    G_x & G_y  \\
    \end{vmatrix}}
$$

For $\frac{dy}{ds}$,
$$F_x\frac{dx}{ds}+F_y\frac{dy}{ds}=-F_s$$
$$G_x\frac{dx}{ds}+G_y\frac{dy}{ds}=-G_s$$

The arguments to obtain the above 2 equations are simply the same as when we obtained $\frac{dy}{dr}$.

Solving,

$$ \frac{dy}{ds}=\frac{
    \begin{vmatrix}
    F_x&  -F_s\\
    G_x & -G_s  \\
    \end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
    F_x&  F_y\\
    G_x & G_y  \\
    \end{vmatrix}}
$$

Now, by the Implicit Function Theorem, we know that we can express r and s as a function of x and y. $r=r'(x,y),s=s'(x,y)$ so as long as the determinant does not vanish. So we shall keep that as a condition without loss of generality.

Continuing, we implicitly differentiate with respect to $dx$,

$$F_r\frac{dr}{dx}+F_s\frac{ds}{dx}=-F_x$$
$$G_r\frac{dr}{dx}+G_s\frac{ds}{dx}=-G_x$$

Solving, we already have $\frac{dr}{dx}, \frac{ds}{dx}$

$$ \frac{dr}{dx}=\frac{
    \begin{vmatrix}
    -F_x&  F_s\\
    -G_x & G_s  \\
    \end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
    F_r&  F_s\\
    G_r & G_s  \\
    \end{vmatrix}}
$$

$$ \frac{ds}{dx}=\frac{
    \begin{vmatrix}
    F_r&  -F_x\\
    G_r & -G_x  \\
    \end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
    F_s&  F_s\\
    G_r & G_s  \\
    \end{vmatrix}}
$$

Hence, we have $\frac{dy}{dr}\frac{dr}{dx}$ is equal to,

$$ \frac{
    \begin{vmatrix}
    F_x&  -F_r\\
    G_x & -G_r  \\
    \end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
    F_x&  F_y\\
    G_x & G_y  \\
    \end{vmatrix}}.\frac{
    \begin{vmatrix}
    -F_x&  F_s\\
    -G_x & G_s  \\
    \end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
    F_r&  F_s\\
    G_r & G_s  \\
    \end{vmatrix}}=\frac{**F_x(-G_r)+G_xF_r**}{F_xG_y-G_xF_y}.\frac{-F_xG_s+G_xF_s}{F_rG_s-G_rF_s}
$$

Likewise, for $\frac{dy}{dr}\frac{dr}{dx}$
$$ \frac{
    \begin{vmatrix}
    F_x&  -F_s\\
    G_x & -G_s  \\
    \end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
    F_x&  F_y\\
    G_x & G_y  \\
    \end{vmatrix}}.\frac{
    \begin{vmatrix}
    F_r&  -F_x\\
    G_r & -G_x  \\
    \end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
    F_r&  F_s\\
    G_r & G_s  \\
    \end{vmatrix}}=\frac{F_x(-G_s)+G_xF_s}{F_xG_y-G_xF_y}.\frac{**-G_xF_r+G_rF_x**}{F_rG_s-G_rF_s}
$$

Bolded terms are negative of each other, and from there it's trivally obvious that the theorem is true.

Comment: Also do note that I've been sloppy with the notation. For every $dx$ you see it's supposed to be $\partial x$. I'm sure there is a faster method to do this though.